# Using Jquery, how can I select all but, exclude certain childs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="container main-navigation">
<div class="col-md-9 text-left float-right collapse-navation">
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-inverse no-transition">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li><a href="#about">Bla bla</a></li>
           <li><a class="langSelection" href="#about">Bla bla</a></li>
```

I have a script that calls:

```
$('.main-navigation')
            .onePageNav({
                scrollThreshold: 0.2,  
                scrollOffset: 79 
            });
```

The problem is, I wish NOT to have this applied to ALL anchors, but wish to exclude those who have a class named: langSelection.

Tried this, but no dice:

```
$('.main-navigation').not(".langSelection")
            .onePageNav({
                scrollThreshold: 0.2, 
                scrollOffset: 79 
            });
```

I would more specify the selector but, the plugin "onePageNav" seem to require a certain element to be selected in order to properly work.

Can I have anyone's help please?

Update:
It seems that, we can, actually, change the selector. So, any solution that does change the selector specificity, may work.

Comment: `$('.main-navigation a:not(a.langSelection)')`

Comment: @dandavis: your solution worked. However, that's not an answer...

Comment: @MEM: worked but not an answer? not sure i follow... anything else need fixin?

Comment: @dandavis All good. Just can't accept it as right answer. Can you please create an answer, instead of a just a comment, so that I can mark as "Accepted Answer". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `:not` pseudo-selector to exclude some elements directly. In this case, you can specify the class as the not condition:

```js
$("#match").on("click", function() {
  $("a:not(.langSelection)").each(function(elem) {
    $(this).css('color', 'green');
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>1</a>
<a class="langSelection">2</a>
<a>3</a>
<button id="match">Match!</button>
```

Comment: Just note that `:not` is a [CSS3 selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp), not a "jQuery selector"

Comment: @DineiA.Rockenbach Yeah, but jQ does funny things. You can't reliably copy every CSS selector to jQ, unfortunately. This one is available, luckily enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gve76ryb/

```
<div class='container'>
    <a>yes</a>
    <a>yes</a>
    <a>yes</a>
    <a class='exclude'>no</a>
    <a>yes</a>    
</div>
```

And the script:

```
$(function(){
    $(".container a:not(.exclude)").css({color: 'red'});
});
```

you can use the :not css selecor, or the .not() jquery selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.main-navigation a').not(".langSelection")
            .onePageNav({
                scrollThreshold: 0.2, 
                scrollOffset: 79 
            });
```

do you just need to add anchor (a) to your selector?